# Censoring words with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have input message from customer for ex:

```
"This is example message with bad words like FWORD"
```

I have pattern that allows me to check this message, but I want output like this:

```
"This is example message with bad words like F***D"
```

I just want to replace all letters with starts except first and last character. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this question only about 1 word or about 1 word in a string and you want to specify which word?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could split the string by a whitespace, loop the words and per word check if it equals the censored word.
If it does, use replace with a regex like:

[`\\B\\w\\B`](https://regex101.com/r/WLdtkC/1)

That would match

- `\B` Assert position where `\b` not matches
- `\w` Word character (Update to your requirements if you want to match more)
- `\B` Assert position where `\b` not matches

As an example:

```
String censored = "FWORD";
String str = "This is example message with bad words like FWORD ";        
String[] words = str.split(" "); 

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].equals(censored)) {
            words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("\\B\\w\\B", "*");         
        }
    }    
System.out.println(String.join(" ", words));
```

That would give you

> This is example message with bad words like F***D

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/JSIUL62259)

If you change `censored` to "message", this will result in:

> This is e*****e message with bad words like FWORD

If you want to list multiple bad words, you could for example create an array with bad words and loop through that array an check each word like [this Demo](http://rextester.com/QXV39945).

Thay way your result could look like:

> This is e*****e message with bad words like F***D

Answer (score 0):

String has a method called .replaceAll(String regex, String replacement).
You can simply call .replaceAll for the words that you want to censor.
Example:

```
    stringToEdit.replaceAll("FWORD","F***D");
```

If you have multiple words you wish to censor, I would suggest keeping multiple regex-es, one for each word in a Map, where the key is the regex and the value is the censored version of the word, or the other way around. You can then go through each of the map entries and use replaceAll on the string.

```
    public static void main (String args[]){

        String toCensor="you can add the dirty words here";

        String censorRegex1="([cC]?)+([hH])+[uU]+[jJ]+([uU+]?)";
        String censorRegex2="[kK]+[Uu]+[rR]+[wW]+[aA]+";

        Map<String, String> censorMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
        censorMap.put(censorRegex1,"c***u");
        censorMap.put(censorRegex2,"k***a");

        for(Map.Entry<String,String> e:censorMap.entrySet()){
            toCensor=toCensor.replaceAll(e.getKey(),e.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println(toCensor);

    }
```

Comment: Ok, but it will replace whole word, what about first and last char? My pattern can match with for ex: "fword", "fffword", "ffwordd" etc.

Comment: depends on the regex you use. for example, what I wrote would replace fword with f***d, ffwordd with ff***dd

Comment: This is my regex:
([cC]?)+([hH])+[uU]+[jJ]+([uU+]?)+|[kK]+[Uu]+[rR]+[wW]+[aA]+

how to do this in that case? :)

Comment: from what my google translate talent can help me, i see that there are two words that you want to filter out, no matter how many multiples of any one letter there are, for example if home was the word: home, hooooome, hommmme, hhhhooooome and so on and so forth, right?

Comment: as mentioned in the edited comment, create a string for each of the regexes, such as "[cC]+[hH]+[uU]+[jJ]+[aA]+" and then have a Map<String,String> in which you add the regex and "c***a". All you need then is to go through the map with a stream, take each entry and use .replaceAll() on the key and value

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a regexp because it may be compiled once making an efficient finite state machine able to do substitution in one pass.

```
String censored_re_str = "(?i)(b)adwor(d)|(v)erybadwor(d)|(y)etmorebadwor(d)";
Pattern censored = Pattern.compile(censored_re_str);

censored.matcher(string_to_replace).replaceAll("$1***$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with apache.commons.lang3 lib)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class FilterApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define your filter
        String[] filterArray = new String[]{"FWORD"};
        // Build a Map with replacements
        Map<String,String> filterMap = new HashMap<>();
        for( String f: filterArray){
            String replacement = f.charAt(0)+StringUtils.leftPad("*", (f.length()-2), '*')+f.charAt(f.length()-1);
            // (?i) means 'CASE_INSENSITIVE' and \\b means 'word boundry'
            filterMap.put("(?i)\\b"+f+"\\b", replacement);
        }
        // Let's do it....
        String result = "This is example message with bad words like FWORD";
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> filter : filterMap.entrySet()) {
            result = result.replaceAll(filter.getKey(), filter.getValue());
        }
        // .. and here is the result
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```